# Centos7: Using Radeon GPU and GT610 Nvidia GPU at the same time with Xwindows

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg, gdm

I am trying to utilize two separate graphics adapters with Gnome on a Centos7 machine.  lspci identifies these two adapters as such:

> 06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce
>   GT 610] (rev a1)
>           Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 2616
>           Kernel driver in use: nouveau
>           Kernel modules: nouveau
>
> 07:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA
>   G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
>           Subsystem: Dell PowerEdge R710 MGA G200eW WPCM450
>           Kernel driver in use: mgag200
>           Kernel modules: mgag200

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf contains the following:

```
Section "OutputClass"
         Identifier "Radeon"
         MatchDriver "radeon"
         Driver "radeon"
EndSection
```

This works correctly using the onboard Radeon card (The machine is a Dell R710).  I then generated a new file - /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nouveau.conf:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Nvidia card"
Driver "nouveau"
BusID "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection
```

and once I issue "systemctl restart gdm" - the GT610 now shows the login screens (I have two monitors attached to this video adapter), however the Radeon stops working.  The only Xorg logfile generated in /var/log is Xorg.0.log.  From looking at it, it appears I need a LAYOUT section and SCREEN section.  I have tried a few different things but cannot get this to work correctly.  In my experimentation, I have found that no matter what I do, I cannot get the radeon card to function with Section "Device" -- it will only work with Section "OutputClass" - is this indication of a problem that precludes the problem of having correct Layout/Screen sections?  Also, xrandr --listproviders shows:

```
Providers: number : 0
```

This is another thing that I am wondering if needs to be corrected before I focus on a correct layout/screen configuration.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing here?  I don't need both adapters to be attached to the same screen, in fact I would prefer they run as separate login instances (one is at the computer rack and the other is to a remote screen/keyboard)

I have another video card (GT710) stubbed out for use in a virtual machine, which I doubt is related to this however thought I would mention it.  lshw -C display shows this, which confirms:

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=pci-stub latency=0
       resources: irq:15 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:b8000000-bfffffff memory:b6000000-b7ffffff ioport:ec80(size=128) memory:da000000-da07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF119 [GeForce GT 610]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c8000000-cfffffff memory:c6000000-c7ffffff ioport:dc80(size=128) memory:dc000000-dc07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G200eW WPCM450
       vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:07:03.0
       version: 0a
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=mgag200 latency=32 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0000000-d07fffff memory:de7fc000-de7fffff memory:de800000-deffffff memory:de000000-de00ffff
```

The Xorg.0.log contains the following (the entire log file was too large to paste):

```
[ 28082.211] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 28082.211] Build Operating System:  3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64 
[ 28082.211] Current Operating System: Linux svr 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 13 22:55:44 UTC 2019 x86_64
[ 28082.211] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=df548a45-26e2-448c-8c6a-964a8bcd1b6b crashkernel=256M intel_iommu=on pci-stub.ids=10de:128b,10de:0e0f vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1
[ 28082.211] Build Date: 09 August 2019  03:27:09AM
[ 28082.211] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.4-7.el7 
[ 28082.211] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 28082.211]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 28082.211] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 28082.211] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Mar 14 10:46:18 2020
[ 28082.212] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 28082.212] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 28082.212] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 28082.212] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 28082.212] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 28082.212] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 28082.212] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[ 28082.212] (**) |   |-->Device "Nvidia card"
[ 28082.212] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 28082.213] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 28082.213] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 28082.213] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 28082.213] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update...  I've removed 10-radeon.conf and 20-nouveau.conf and created a 20-vid.conf for all video configuration here.  Just easier to keep track of what I'm trying, etc.  At the moment I appear to have radeon recognized in the logfile without errors but the screen is blank.  Previously when it wasn't working there was a cursor in the top left corner.  Now the screen is completely black.  I think this is an indication of positive progress.  The VGA monitor on the radeon card was not detected in any way before when the nvidia card was active.  Now, I see recognition of the monitor and adapter name in the logfile, and the radeon is defined as DEVICE,not OUTPUTCLASS.

Also, I now have information in xrandr --listproviders:

```
[user@svr ~]$ xrandr  --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x64 cap: 0x7, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 2 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:nouveau
```

I feel like I'm getting closer, but still missing something.  Anyone have a clue what it might be?

This is the xorg config now:

```
Section "Module"
        Load            "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor2"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen 0"
        Device          "Nvidia card"
        Monitor         "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen 1"
        Device          "Nvidia card"
        Monitor         "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen 2"
        Device          "radeon"
        Monitor         "Monitor2"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "Main Layout"
        Screen  0 "Screen 0"
        Screen  1 "Screen 1"
        Screen  2 "Screen 2"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "Radeon"
        #MatchDriver "radeon"
        Driver "modesetting"
        BusID "PCI:7:3:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "Nvidia card"
        Driver "nouveau"
        BusID "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection
```

And this is some of the xorg.0.log file.  With this being a new post I can include more of it this time:

```
  [ 34847.284] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 34847.284] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 34847.285] (==) ServerLayout "Main Layout"
[ 34847.285] (**) |-->Screen "Screen 0" (0)
[ 34847.285] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[ 34847.285] (**) |   |-->Device "Nvidia card"
[ 34847.285] (**) |-->Screen "Screen 1" (1)
[ 34847.285] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[ 34847.286] (**) |   |-->Device "Nvidia card"
[ 34847.286] (**) |-->Screen "Screen 2" (2)
[ 34847.286] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor2"
[ 34847.286] (**) |   |-->Device "Radeon"
[ 34847.286] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 34847.286] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 34847.286] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 34847.286] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 34847.286] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 34847.286] (==) FontPath set to:
    catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,
    built-ins
[ 34847.286] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[ 34847.286] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 34847.286] (II) Loader magic: 0x5650e5f28020
[ 34847.286] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 34847.286]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 34847.286]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[ 34847.286]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 34847.286]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 34847.287] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[ 34847.288] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 34847.309] (--) PCI: (4@0:0:0) 10de:128b:3842:2713 rev 161, Mem @ 0xdb000000/16777216, 0xb8000000/134217728, 0xb6000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ec80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[ 34847.309] (--) PCI: (6@0:0:0) 10de:104a:3842:2616 rev 161, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xc8000000/134217728, 0xc6000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc80/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[ 34847.309] (--) PCI:*(7@0:3:0) 102b:0532:1028:0235 rev 10, Mem @ 0xd0000000/8388608, 0xde7fc000/16384, 0xde800000/8388608, BIOS @ 0x????????/65536
[ 34847.309] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[ 34847.309] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 34847.309] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 34847.309] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.309]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[ 34847.309]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 34847.309]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 34847.309] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 34847.310] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 34847.311] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.311]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 34847.311]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 34847.311] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[ 34847.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[ 34847.312] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.312]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 1.0.15
[ 34847.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 34847.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 34847.312] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 34847.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 34847.312] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.312]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[ 34847.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 34847.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 34847.312] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[ 34847.312] (II) Unloading modesetting
[ 34847.312] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[ 34847.312] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 34847.312] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[ 34847.312] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[ 34847.312]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[ 34847.312]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[ 34847.312]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[ 34847.312]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[ 34847.313]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[ 34847.313] (++) using VT number 1

[ 34847.348] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[ 34847.348] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
[ 34847.348] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 34847.348] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 34847.348] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 34847.349] (--) NOUVEAU(0): Chipset: "NVIDIA NVD9"
[ 34847.349] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Screen 0" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): RGB weight 888
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Using HW cursor
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Allowed maximum DRI level 2.
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): GLX sync to VBlank enabled.
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Page flipping enabled
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Swap limit set to 1 [Max allowed 2]
[ 34847.349] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Page flipping synced to vblank by kernel.
[ 34847.349] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Initializing outputs ...
[ 34847.393] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-1 using monitor section Monitor0
[ 34847.439] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-2 has no monitor section
[ 34847.440] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[ 34847.440] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 3 crtcs needed for screen.
[ 34847.441] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Allocated crtc nr. 0 to this screen.
[ 34847.441] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Allocated crtc nr. 1 to this screen.
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID for output DVI-I-1
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: 4079  Serial#: 1094206284
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Year: 2012  Week: 49
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Digital Display Input
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 44  vert.: 25
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Gamma: 2.20
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): redX: 0.636 redY: 0.339   greenX: 0.319 greenY: 0.618
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): blueX: 0.154 blueY: 0.049   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported established timings:
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 720x400@70Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 640x480@60Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 640x480@75Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@60Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@75Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported standard timings:
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #2: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): clock: 97.8 MHz   Image Size:  443 x 249 mm
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): h_active: 1600  h_sync: 1648  h_sync_end 1680 h_blank_end 1760 h_border: 0
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): v_active: 900  v_sync: 903  v_sync_end 908 v_blanking: 926 v_border: 0
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Serial No: W5HWR2C7A8CL
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Monitor name: DELL P2012H
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID (in hex):
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   00ffffffffffff0010ac79404c433841
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   31160103802c1978eafda5a256519e27
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   0c5054a54b00714f8180a9c001010101
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   0101010101012f2640a060841a303020
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   3500bbf91000001a000000ff00573548
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   57523243374138434c0a000000fc0044
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   454c4c205032303132480a20000000fd
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   00384c1e5311000a2020202020200002
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing probed modes for output DVI-I-1
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0   97.75  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz eP)
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.486] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.487] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID for output DVI-I-2
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer: DEL  Model: 4079  Serial#: 892678722
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Year: 2012  Week: 30
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Digital Display Input
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 44  vert.: 25
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Gamma: 2.20
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): redX: 0.636 redY: 0.339   greenX: 0.319 greenY: 0.618
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): blueX: 0.154 blueY: 0.049   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported established timings:
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 720x400@70Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 640x480@60Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 640x480@75Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@60Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@75Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported standard timings:
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #0: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #1: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #2: hsize: 1600  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 49321
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): clock: 97.8 MHz   Image Size:  443 x 249 mm
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): h_active: 1600  h_sync: 1648  h_sync_end 1680 h_blank_end 1760 h_border: 0
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): v_active: 900  v_sync: 903  v_sync_end 908 v_blanking: 926 v_border: 0
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Serial No: 8VVND27Q552B
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Monitor name: DELL P2012H
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 175 MHz
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID (in hex):
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   00ffffffffffff0010ac794042323535
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   1e160103802c1978eafda5a256519e27
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   0c5054a54b00714f8180a9c001010101
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   0101010101012f2640a060841a303020
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   3500bbf91000001a000000ff00385656
[ 34847.532] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   4e44323751353532420a000000fc0044
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   454c4c205032303132480a20000000fd
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0):   00384c1e5311000a2020202020200062
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing probed modes for output DVI-I-2
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0   97.75  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz eP)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.533] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-1 connected
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-2 connected
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using spanning desktop for initial modes
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-1 using initial mode 1600x900 +0+0
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-I-2 using initial mode 1600x900 +1600+0
[ 34847.534] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 34847.534] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Virtual size is 3200x900 (pitch 0)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1600x900": 97.8 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 55.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1600x900"x60.0   97.75  1600 1648 1680 1760  900 903 908 926 +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz eP)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1280x1024": 135.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 80.0 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1280x1024": 108.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 64.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1152x864": 108.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 67.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1024x768": 78.8 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 60.0 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1024x768": 65.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 48.4 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 49.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 46.9 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 40.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 37.9 kHz, 60.3 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "640x480": 31.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 37.5 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "640x480": 25.2 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 31.5 kHz, 59.9 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "720x400": 28.3 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 31.5 kHz, 70.1 Hz
[ 34847.535] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.535] (==) NOUVEAU(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 34847.535] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 34847.535] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 34847.535] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 34847.535] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.535]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 34847.535]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 34847.535] (II) Loading sub module "shadowfb"
[ 34847.536] (II) LoadModule: "shadowfb"
[ 34847.536] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libshadowfb.so
[ 34847.536] (II) Module shadowfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.536]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 34847.536]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 34847.536] (II) modeset(1): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Screen 2" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 34847.536] (==) modeset(1): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 34847.536] (==) modeset(1): RGB weight 888
[ 34847.536] (==) modeset(1): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 34847.536] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[ 34847.536] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[ 34847.536] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[ 34847.543] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.543]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.1
[ 34847.543]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 34847.619] (II) modeset(1): Refusing to try glamor on llvmpipe
[ 34847.619] (EE) modeset(1): glamor initialization failed
[ 34847.619] (II) modeset(1): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[ 34847.619] (II) modeset(1): Double-buffered shadow updates: on
[ 34847.652] (II) modeset(1): Output VGA-1 using monitor section Monitor2
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): EDID for output VGA-1
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Manufacturer: ADE  Model: 836  Serial#: 0
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Year: 2000  Week: 2
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): EDID Version: 1.1
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Sync:  Separate
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 30  vert.: 23
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Gamma: 2.20
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): redX: 0.595 redY: 0.350   greenX: 0.315 greenY: 0.575
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): blueX: 0.150 blueY: 0.125   whiteX: 0.300 whiteY: 0.320
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): Supported established timings:
[ 34847.685] (II) modeset(1): 720x400@70Hz
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): 640x480@60Hz
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): 800x600@56Hz
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): 800x600@60Hz
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): 1024x768@60Hz
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Supported standard timings:
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Supported detailed timing:
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): clock: 65.0 MHz   Image Size:  304 x 228 mm
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): h_active: 1024  h_sync: 1048  h_sync_end 1184 h_blank_end 1344 h_border: 0
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): v_active: 768  v_sync: 771  v_sync_end 777 v_blanking: 806 v_border: 0
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Ranges: V min: 60 V max: 65 Hz, H min: 31 H max: 69 kHz,
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Serial No: ADE2100V2-0AF
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Monitor name: ADE2100V2 FLK
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): EDID (in hex):
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   00ffffffffffff000485360800000000
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   020a0101681e1778e86d8c9859509326
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   204c52a3080081800100010001800100
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   01000100010064190040410026301888
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   360030e410000018000000fd003c411f
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   45ff000a202020202020000000ff0041
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   44453231303056322d304146000000fc
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1):   0041444532313030563220464c4b003d
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Output VGA-1 connected
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[ 34847.686] (II) modeset(1): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1024x768 +0+0
[ 34847.686] (==) modeset(1): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 34847.686] (==) modeset(1): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 34847.686] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 34847.686] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 34847.687] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 34847.687] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.687]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[ 34847.687]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 34847.687] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[ 34847.687] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[ 34847.687] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[ 34847.687] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.687]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.1.0
[ 34847.687]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 34847.689] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Channel setup complete.
[ 34847.689] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [COPY] async initialised.
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Hardware support for Present enabled
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: nouveau
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nouveau
[ 34847.690] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[ 34847.690] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[ 34847.690] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[ 34847.690] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 34847.690]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.6.0
[ 34847.690]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[ 34847.690] (II) EXA(0): Driver allocated offscreen pixmaps
[ 34847.690] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[ 34847.690] (II)         Solid
[ 34847.690] (II)         Copy
[ 34847.690] (II)         Composite (RENDER acceleration)
[ 34847.690] (II)         UploadToScreen
[ 34847.690] (II)         DownloadFromScreen
[ 34847.690] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Backing store enabled
[ 34847.690] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [XvMC] Associated with Nouveau GeForce 8/9 Textured Video.
[ 34847.690] (II) NOUVEAU(0): [XvMC] Extension initialized.
[ 34847.690] (==) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS enabled
[ 34847.691] (==) modeset(1): Backing store enabled
[ 34847.691] (==) modeset(1): Silken mouse enabled
[ 34847.691] (II) modeset(1): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[ 34847.691] (==) modeset(1): DPMS enabled
[ 34847.691] (II) Found 2 VGA devices: arbiter wrapping enabled
[ 34847.691] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that the radeon screen was in fact active as just a console;  When I issued a reboot command, the console status updates during the shutdown process were displayed on that monitor.